# How to store entries of complete menu and omnicomplete menu in variables without triggering the popup menu?

Tags: autocompletion, popup-menu

Is there a way to store the results of `<C-N>` or `<C-X><C-O>` from the insert mode in a string or list variable without triggering the respective popup menus to display onscreen?  For example, I am able to store the output of the UltiSnips plugin without triggering a popup by using the following:

```
    redir => l:message
        silent call UltiSnips#ListSnippets()
    redir END
```

I know that once a popup menu is displayed, I can see its content with the `complete_info()` function.  However, I do not want to open and close multiple popups in succession, since this results in screen flickers.

Ultimately, I wish to create a single popup menu with the results compiled from many other popup menus.

Comment: I think there’s a complete() function that may help. I would search around in the docs

Comment: @Ben, Yes, I will be using the complete() function to display my final single popup menu.  However, first I need help gathering information from vim's various popup menus, without causing those popup menus to show onscreen.

Comment: The only other thing I can find is `getcompletion` which is specific to the vim command line.

Comment: @Ben, Thank you for the latest suggestion.  `getcompletion` is not quite what I am looking for, as it can only show vim command line completions.  It is my suspicion that what I want is not currently possible.  `complete_info()` itself is a very new function added to the later versions of vim.  If there were a way to gather all drop-down menu items without displaying the drop-down menus first, then authors of plugins such as `mucomplete` would have done that already, instead of just showing individual drop-down menus in order.